# How to fix an AttributeError in django?

Tags: python, django, view, model

I am trying to return the list of playlists that are associated with the current logged in user and I get an error saying:
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'has_header

I have included what I believe are the relevant parts of the code below.  Any advice on how to fix this?

## views.py

```
playlist = UserPlaylist.objects.filter(profile=request.user)
return playlist
```

## models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)         

class Playlist(models.Model):
    playlist = models.CharField('Playlist', max_length = 2000, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.playlist
    
class Video(models.Model):
    video_url = models.URLField('Link to video', max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.video_url

class UserPlaylist(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(User)
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(Playlist)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.playlist)

class Videoplaylist(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video)
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(UserPlaylist)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.playlist)
```

Comment: Could you post the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Post the whole view function. As it stands right now is wrong. It doesn't return an HttpResponse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out...I'm doing return instead of print.  Rookie mistake.